# How to execute a function if a manual refresh is performed

Tags: php, jquery

The Index page is designed such tat It retrieves Data after login via a jquery request... My Doubt is tat How to maintain the page if a manual refresh is performed or can i perform any function if a manual refresh is performed? Here is some of my Code..

Checklogin.php

```
    <?php
           session_start();
           include('dbconnect.php');
           $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
           $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['pass']);
           $pass=filter_var($pass, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
           $email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
           $query="SELECT * from `users` WHERE `email`='$email' and `pass`='$pass'";
           $res=mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query");
           $res1=mysql_num_rows($res);
           $name="guest";
           if($res1 == 0)
           {    
          $query="SELECT * from `users` WHERE `email`='$email'";
          $res=mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query");
          $res2=mysql_num_rows($res);
          if($res2>0){
        $code=3;
        echo json_encode(array('name'=>$name,'code'=>$code));
          }
          else{
        $code=2;
        echo json_encode(array('name'=>$name,'code'=>$code));
          }
        }
        else
        {
    $code=1;
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $name=$row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    $query="select * from crown1 where email='".$_SESSION['email']."';";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
                    $level=$row['level'];
                    $points=$row['points'];
                    $rank=$row['rank'];
                    $times="time".$level;
                    $timest=$row[$times];
                    $query="select * from qna where level=".$level.";";
                    $res9=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    $row9=mysqli_fetch_array($res9);
                    $title=$row9['title'];
                    $qn=$row9['qnlink'];
                    $_SESSION['title']=$title;
                    $_SESSION['qnlink']=$qn;
                    $_SESSION['level']=$level;
                    $_SESSION['points']=$points;
                    $_SESSION['timest']=$timest;
                    $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;

    //echo $_SESSION['email'];
    echo json_encode(array('name'=>$_SESSION['name'],'code'=>$code));

    }
?>
```

leader.js

```
    var loadData = function(){
        var url = 'Leaders.php';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $('#Leaders').empty().append('<ul style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; list-style-type:none; width:100%">');
        $.each(data, function(index, data) {
           $('#Leaders>ul').append("<li style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 30px; width:100%'>&nbsp; #"+data.rank+" &nbsp;&nbsp;"+data.name+"<span class='myNumber' name='n1' style='float:right;'> "+data.points+" &nbsp;</span></li>");
        });
          $('#Leaders').append('</ul>');
   });
      var url = 'Game.php';
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $('#points').empty().append(data.points);
        $('#level').empty().append(data.level);
        $('#ranking').empty().append(data.rank);
        $('#levelUsers').empty().append(data.users);
        $('#totalPlayers').empty().append(data.nousers);
        $('#titlediv>div>h3>center').empty().append(data.title);
        $('#game3').empty().append("<img src='"+data.qnlink+"' style='width:700px;height:250px;'/>");
        //setIntervalOnce(loadData, 5000);
      });
}
```

And I'll call LoadData() after Checklogin is called...

Comment: _manual refresh_? You mean via the browsers refresh button?

Comment: this looks like you are just wanting to run a function if the page is loaded and the user is logged in. Why specifically if the browser is reloaded manually?

Comment: Yes... Because all The content which i load via This LoadData() is lost and the page goes Blank... i.e. on Refresh

Comment: so why not just on page load check login, then if logged in load data?  put that in a document ready event and it seems your problem is over. I think the confusion here is why it seems you only want to do this if the page is "reloaded" and not just if the page is visited at all. Any method you use to detect a manual refresh is probably a lot more work than needs to be done and is almost certainly not a reliable means.

Comment: Because the user needs to see a Welcome page when He's not logged in and Needs to see His page when Logged in... If its given on Page Load , He'll see only the Default Page, (which i Don't want him to see)

Comment: @KaiQing Yes, It worked , I added another loadData() at the end of Document.ready and it works... Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way to 100% detect if the page is loaded manually or not as the information used to determine this can always be spoofed if someone really wanted to. But you could do something like so:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* Page was loaded via AJAX */
} else {
    /* Page wasn't loaded via AJAX, e.g. direct url entered, page refreshed, referred from another page. */
}
```